# Wordpress blog doesnt work after putting web server behind a reverse proxy

Tags: squid, wordpress

My blog has been working fine for over a year now, but now that I've put the server behind a reverse proxy it gets stuck in an infinite loop.

Other websites work fine with this new proxy; I can still login etc... so it's not a cookie problem.

I've tried it on another machine and it has the same problem.

This is my `squid.conf`:

```
#HTTP Reversing
#Set the port
http_port 1337 defaultsite=londinium.arcath.net vhost
#Londinium Hosts
cache_peer 10.0.0.45 parent 80 0 no-query originserver name=londinium
cache_peer_domain londinium londinium.arcath.net
#Whitefall
cache_peer 10.0.0.40 parent 80 0 no-query originserver name=whitefall
cache_peer_domain whitefall .arcath.net .ed-itsolutions.com


acl all src 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/255.255.255.255
acl to_localhost dst 127.0.0.0/8
acl SSL_ports port 443          # https
acl SSL_ports port 563          # snews
acl SSL_ports port 873          # rsync
acl Safe_ports port 80          # http
acl Safe_ports port 21          # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443         # https
acl Safe_ports port 70          # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210         # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280         # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488         # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591         # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777         # multiling http
acl Safe_ports port 631         # cups
acl Safe_ports port 873         # rsync
acl Safe_ports port 901         # SWAT
acl web dstdomain 10.0.0.40
acl purge method PURGE
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

http_access allow all
http_access allow localhost
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't running the latest version of WordPress, reverse proxying isn't supported. In short, WP doesn't know how to rewrite the URLs that it dynamically generates.

It's pretty simple to patch WP and fix the issue, though. This thread on the WP support forum has detailed instructions:

- http://wordpress.org/support/topic/200543